# How to access a variable created in one event listener in another?

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I’m making a basic color generator that generates a random hex or RGB color depending on which button is pressed. I’ve made a constructor function that runs each time a button is pressed, generating a new color with a bunch of methods for generating light/dark variations, translating between color spaces, etc.

My UI has 3 buttons: hex, translate, and RGB. I currently have code written on the event listener for translating that will change between hex/RGB, but it would be more concise if I could use a method from the same color object generated when I click hex/rgb.

Currently, I have the following code when I click either the hex or rgb buttons:

```
hex.addEventListener (‘click’) function () {
     const newColor = new Color();
     setStylesHex(newColor);
}
```

In an ideal world, I would be able to have something like this on the translate button (using the newColor variable generated above), but I am running into scope issues:

```
trans.addEventListener (‘click’, function() {
     if (head.innerText[0] === 1) {
     setStylesRGB(newColor);
     } else {
          setStylesHex(newColor);
     }
})
```

I haven’t really tried anything besides reproducing my translator code on the event listener for the translate button. I’m really lost for how to get my desired functionality and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the declaration for `newColor` in a scope where both functions can access it:

```
let newColor;

hex.addEventListener (‘click’) function () {
     newColor = new Color();
     setStylesHex(newColor);
}

trans.addEventListener (‘click’, function() {
     if (head.innerText[0] === 1) {
     setStylesRGB(newColor);
     } else {
          setStylesHex(newColor);
     }
})
```

Comment: Would this allow multiple colors to be generated, though? I have it written as-is so that each time someone presses the hex button, a new color is generated.

——
Thank you so much! It works! Sorry for the silly question!

Comment: The way it's currently written, the buttons will always operate on the newest colour generated.